# Pulse train rect function

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, dirichlet-convolution

[image]Why $ X_\delta (f) = \frac{4A}{3} ( 1 - \frac{1}{2} rect \frac{f}{B} ) $ is equal to The $ X_\delta (f) $ signal I wrote here ? [image] my book obtained the same equation I wrote on the paper but , before doing the convolution to obtain the rebuilt signal  , it change the rect signal ( that we both obtained )  to the first I wrote initially ..

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{4A}{3}(1 - \frac{1}{2}\Pi(\frac{f}{B})) = \frac{2A}{3}\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty}\Pi(\frac{f-2kB}{3B})$$
where $\Pi(f) = 1$ for $|f| \lt \frac{1}{2}$ and zero otherwise?

Comment: Yes ! I don’t understand why these two are the same. I made the exercise in the same way of my book, but I’m totally lost in this part

Comment: Well, that isn't true. $\Pi(\frac{f}{B})$ is zero outside $|f|\lt \frac{B}{2}$ and $\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty}\Pi(\frac{f-2kB}{3B})$ isn't even continuous.

Comment: Ok , so probably I don’t understand the final part of my exercise because the rest is the same .. I have the signal $ A sinc( 3Bt ) $ that enters into an ideal sampler with a sampling rate of fc=2B. I found that the Nquist condition isn’t verified and after I found $ X_\delta(t) $. I have to find X rebuilt (f) that is the product of $X \delta(f) $ and $ H_{reb} (f) = {T_c} \rect \frac{f}{f_c} $. At this point my book change the formula of $ X_\delta $. With “my” method I also obtained the same graph but I don’t understand the analytic expression

Comment: Please make your question clear and use MathJax for equations in your question.

Comment: Sorry , i have $ x(t) = A sinc (3B t ) $ that enters into an ideal sampler c(t). The output of this sampler is $ x_\delta (t) $. This signal $ x_delta (t) $ enters into a filter $ H_{ric}(f) = T_c rect (\frac{f}{f_c} ) $ , where $ T_c = \frac{1}{f_c} $ and $ f_c = 2B $. The output of this filter is $x_{ric} (t) $. I have to find this $ x_{ric} (t) $ but , before I found $ X_\delta (f) \frac{A}{3} rect (\frac{f- kB2 } {3B } $. This result should be ok. Now $ X_ric (f) = X_\delta (f) H_{ric} (f) $ but at this point , analytically my book change the $ X_\delta (f) $ into the one I posted

Comment: What's the equation for $c(t)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117211/discussion-between-elena-martini-and-s-h-w).

Comment: $ c(t) = cos ( 2 \pi f_0 t ) $ , sorry !

Comment: So how does $c(t) = \cos(2\pi f_0 t)$ sample the signal? I think it's better to write the original question in detail.